# How to list 2-3 dates and time ranges that you could do an interview

Tags: interviewing

How to list dates and time ranges to do interviews

Comment: Do you mean that you've applied for a position, and they've asked you to list 2-3 dates and time ranges when you're available to interview? If so, what about that do you need help with? Just figure out a few times when you can do the interview, and then reply with those.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. Is there some sort of complication here that means the dates and times are not easy to list?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, you can email something like this to the recruiter:

Hello Mr. recruiter,

Here is my interview availability:

1. Monday (April 25) : from 9:00 AM to 11:30 AM (Timezone: CST)
2. Tuesday (April 26) : from 2:00 PM to 4:30 PM (Timezone: CST)

Best Regards,

Nadia Fredericks